# SSIS Script Task not failing with DTS.TaskResult

Tags: ssis

We require SSIS Script Task to fail on certain condition

```
If var_status = "Y"
Msgbox("Error Found")
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
End If
```

But when we run it goes in the IF condition but doesn't failed the script Task.

Can anyone please suggest

Comment: There is no loop in the code you pasted above. Can you paste the whole code? Also, you are not returning when the failure condition is satisfied i.e. use **Return** within the **If** condition, as this will break the (invisible) loop.

Comment: apologies - when I say look I mean it goes in IF condition, but doesn't make task fail.

Comment: I have updated the code. Msgbox does get execute, but task doesn't fail.

Comment: If var_status = "Y" - this is error condition for me.

Comment: Add **Return** just before the **End If**, this should fail the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If var_status = "Y"
    Msgbox("Error Found")
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    Return
End If
```

**Assuming **ScriptResults.Failure** is the same as **Dts.Results.Failure**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this technique:

try
    {

```
   //Code goes here that may throw exception or succeed
   Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

}
catch (Exception e)
{

   //Outputs a message to the Output window of SSDT/BIDS
   Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "My Task Name", e.message, String.Empty, 0);

  // Makes a package fail (or intercept in Event Handler)
   Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
```

}